# Unsatisfied while opening home folder for the first two time

Tags: 14.04, files, gui, interface, taskbar

*Question may be little logistic*

- Open home folder for the first time clicking ***files*** in the taskbar.
- Go to some drive you have partitioned and open a file from there.
  ***Make sure you are not in the home folder***.
- Lets open chrome, firefox any program, again press the ***files*** icon in the taskbar,***now this again opens the home folder***.
- **Why doesn't it shows the previous screen i.e. the screen I opened earlier where I was  exploring files on the partitioned drive.Why new home folder again?**